# Word renames heading 1,Heading 2, and Heading 3 styles when inserted as a quick part

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365, microsoft-word-2016

I am running Office 365, Word 2016. I have a document which I use a source for a quick part. The heading styles in the source document are Heading 1, Heading 2 and Heading 3 as per normal. I save the content of the source document as a quick part. When I insert the quick part into another document Word renames the Heading 1, 2 and 3 styles as:

```
Heading 1,Topic Heading 1
Heading 2,Topic Heading 2
Heading 3,Topic Sub Heading,zz3
```

All style options, such as paragraph level formatting, font formatting are unchecked. Renaming the styles does not work. They reappear every time I insert the quick part. 
I have checked all the templates in the startup folder, deleted Normal.dotm and let Word recreate it.
I cannot find anywhere where the styles are named Heading 1,Topic Heading 1 etc.
If I paste from the document that I use as my quick part source into a new document the problem does not occur. It occurs only when I insert the text as a quick part.
Is this a bug a in Word or is there some setting I need to turn off in styles, quick parts? It's very annoying as I am writing VBA to manage styles and I have to write extra code to get around the odd style names. Where is the "zz3" tacked on to the end of the Heading Style 3 coming from? I have tested this on another virtual machine running the same version of Word and Office and it also happens. Any clues as to what's going on?

Thanks but your solution does not work. I did some further tests.
I cannot find any reference to the odd heading names in the document I use as the source for the quick part, the quick part itself, the normal template - I deleted it and let Word re-create it - or in any of the Word user templates or global templates. 
I saved my quick part text in notepad to remove all formatting, saved it as a quick part, applied the heading styles and inserted it in to a document, with the same result; Word renamed all heading styles to as before.

In a nutshell, when I insert a quick part that has heading styles 1, 2 or 3, Word renames the styles as above.
I can only conclude that this is a bug or something weird going on with my installation.
Could anybody kindly confirm if they experience the same kind of behavior when inserting a quick part with heading styles 1, 2 or 3?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the Quick Parts are stored with these style names set on them. If the Quick Part source document is a template:

1. Open a new blank document.
2. Validate the Heading 1, 2 and 3 are correctly named in this document.
3. From the Developer tab click the Document Template button and use the Attach function to attached your Quick Part template to it.
4. Insert one of the Quick Parts and verify the style name.
5. Assuming the style name is incorrect, now correct the name by editing it using Modify Style.
6. Re-save the Quick Part, overwriting the incorrect one.
7. Test the Quick Part again by inserting it into the document.
8. Repeat these steps for the other two Quick Parts.